# How to query preg_match_all results in foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, preg-match-all, tagging

So I am working on a user tagging system like twitter where users can tag each other in comments like so: "blablabla @username blablabla". I am using preg_replace to find and convert "@username" in a text into a clickable link, and preg_match_all when inserting to a database.

```
$text = preg_replace('/(^|\s)@(\w+)/', '$1<a href="profile.php?poet_id=$2" class="small">@$2</a>', $text);
```

And

```
    $sanitized_comment = trim(mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment'])));

if (preg_match_all("/(^|\s)@(\w+)/", $sanitized_comment, $matches)) {
        $mentions = array_unique($matches[0]);

        foreach($mentions as $mention) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `comments_mentions` SET `cm_comment_id` = @last_comment_id, `cm_mentioned` = '" . $mention . "', `cm_mentioner` = " . (int)$session_user_id . "");
        }
    }
```

This works fine.

What I'm trying to do now is to find and store the "user_id" of the users that have been tagged in the text, instead of their "username".

I have tried doing

```
    $sanitized_comment = trim(mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment'])));

if (preg_match_all("/(^|\s)@(\w+)/", $sanitized_comment, $matches)) {
    $mentions = array_unique($matches[0]);

    foreach($mentions as $mention) {
        $user_id_from_username = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE lower(`username`) = lower(substr('" . $mention . "', 2))"));
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `comments_mentions` SET `cm_comment_id` = @last_comment_id, `cm_mentioned` = " . $user_id_from_username . ", `cm_mentioner` = " . (int)$session_user_id . "");
    }
}
```

But this only inserts one row (the first value) into the database, even if several people were tagged.

How do I properly query the "user_id" of each mentioned users "username", and then store these ids in rows (multiple if several people were tagged) in my database?

Comment: Isn't a `JOIN` what you're looking for? Additionally, `mysql_` functions have been deprecated ages ago, consider using the newer `mysqli_` functions or `PDO`.

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I will look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `var_dump($matches)` before `$mentions = array_unique($matches[0]);`. I am not sure, but I would expect the usernames to be stored in `$matches[2]`.

You could also give `(\w+)` a name to make things easier. The pattern should look something like:

```
/(^|\s)@(?P<username>\w+)/
```

When doing `preg_match_all` you can get the usernames like this:

```
$mentions = array_unique($matches['username']);
```

Also what [@CharlotteDunois](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815579/how-to-query-preg-match-all-results-in-foreach-loop/38816568#comment64998579_38815579) said in the comment. Using `mysql` is bad. Use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Thank you so much! Assigning a name to (\w+) like you said did the trick. I will heed your advice on switching to PDO or mysqli.